# Error in vault-agent-init to validate secret id

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I'm trying to inject secrets to a pod using a vault-agent-injector bt the vault-agent-init trowh me this error:

```
    ==> Vault Agent started! Log data will stream in below:
    ==> Vault Agent configuration:                         Api Address 1: http://bufconn
                Cgo: disabled
                Log Level: info
                Version: Vault v1.14.0, built 2023-06-19T11:40:23Z
             Version Sha: 13a649f860186dffe3f3a4459814d87191efc321
2023-12-21T11:20:29.721Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: creating file sink
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: file sink configured: path=/home/vault/.token mode=-rw-r-----
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting auth handler
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.sink.server: starting sink server
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO] agent.template.server: starting template server
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.exec.server: starting exec server
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.exec.server: no env templates or exec config, exiting
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [INFO] (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
2023-12-21T11:20:29.722Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error getting path or data from method: error="no known role ID" backoff=1s
```

this is my configmap.yaml file where I testing the configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config-init.hcl: |
    "auto_auth" = {
      "method" = {
        "config" = {
          "role" = "approle"
        }
        "type" = "approle"
        "config" = {
          "role_id_file_path" = "auth/approle/role/role-id"
          "secret_id_file_path " = "auth/approle/role/secret-id"
        }
      }

      "sink" = {
        "config" = {
          "path" = "/home/vault/.token"
        }
        "type" = "file"
      }
    }

    "exit_after_auth" = true
    "pid_file" = "/home/vault/.pid"

    "template" = {
      "contents" = "{{- with secret \"app-secrets/app-chart\" -}}DB_PASSWORD: {{ .Data.DB_PASSWORD }}{{- end }}"
      "destination" = "/vault/secrets/db-creds"
    }

    "vault" = {
      "address" = "https://vault.com"
      "tls_skip_verify" = true
    }
  config.hcl: |
    "auto_auth" = {
      "method" = {
        "config" = {
          "role" = "approle"
        }
        "type" = "approle"
        "config" = {
          "role_id_file_path" = "auth/approle/role/role-id"
          "role_id_file_path" = "auth/approle/role/secret-id"
        }
      }

      "sink" = {
        "config" = {
          "path" = "/home/vault/.token"
        }
        "type" = "file"
      }
    }

    "exit_after_auth" = false
    "pid_file" = "/home/vault/.pid"

    "template" = {
      "contents" =  "{{- with secret \"app-secrets/app-chart\" -}}DB_PASSWORD: {{ .Data.DB_PASSWORD }}{{- end }}"
      "destination" = "/vault/secrets/db-creds"
    }

    "vault" = {
      "address" = "https://vault.com"
      "tls_skip_verify" = true
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

I read from other stackoverflow post I need to recreate the `vault write -f auth/approle/role/secret-id` but it not works. Maybe I need to create other secret-id ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified the `role_id` and `secret_id` files on the container filesystem?

Comment: the files exists, but I think the init container don't take the correct url for do the request to the vault API

Comment: I changed the auth method to kubernetes using a ServiceAccount for the authentication